# jquery 1.7 unable to trigger events in window.onload

Tags: jquery

Hi i have the following jquery code:

```
jQuery.noConflict()
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#input").on("blur", function() {
     alert("item is blur");
  }
});
```

Now later on i have

```
window.onload=function() {
    jQuery("#input").blur();
}
```

The window.onload doesn't seem to get fire?

What is wrong? I want to be able to have events register in ready than in onload fire them depending on the loaded value? Now if i blur it manually it works, but not while the onload method is being activated.

Comment: What does the JavaScript console tell you? If you're not using one, you really should be. It would identify errors you encounter and help identify typoes / syntax errors such as those in the above sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#input").on("blur", function() {
     alert("item is blur");
  }); //<-- );
});
```

Works: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/mvtxW/

To detect such errors, just open the console. You would have seen:

> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

Comment: Also missing a semicolon after the noConflict()

Comment: I'd love to know how not. ;-) Or in other words, it doesn't sit right in my brain and I need to be educated-- not that I think you're wrong.

Comment: Semicolons are optional in JavaScript. [They get inserted automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion). It is better to explicitly include them, but leaving them is technically not an error.

Comment: Thanks, Felix. At some point in time I may have even known this, but when you get into habits (in this case, good ones I suppose) you can sometimes start to think of your habits as rules.

Comment: I know :) It gives me the shivers when I see JavaScript code without semicolons ;)

Comment: One note: You can't minify JavaScript code without semicolons - or it is somewhat difficult

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
jQuery(window).load(function()
{
    jQuery("#input").blur(); 
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks. but i am adding jquery to existing legacy application so the onload function is define by 

     `window.onload=function(){
            alert ('loading item');
            jQuery("#input").blur();
      }`
Now during page loading it goes to "item is blur", loading item.. than stop. I expect it to be "item is blur" after page completely finishes loading.

Comment: btw if i do what you suggested than the blur goes into effect but i am mixing in legacy app.